# HorizontalPodAutoscaler deployment fails post GKE upgrade to 1.26

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling, horizontal-scaling

We are using gcp and have recently updated to gke 1.26 earlier it was 1.16 something.

We had a horizontal pod autoscaler defined for one of our deployment
using version :- :autoscaling/v2beta2"
now since "autoscaling/v2beta2" has been removed from 1.26 gke,
we have updated the hpa manifest with version as "v2".

While trying helm upgrade we still get below errors:-

```
UPGRADE FAILED: unable to build 
kubernetes objects from current release manifest: resource mapping not found for name:
 "***-autoscaler" namespace: "*****" from "": no matches for kind "HorizontalPodAutoscaler" in version "autoscaling/v2beta2" ensure CRDs are installed first.
```

Although there is no reference to "autoscaling/v2beta2" in any deployment file.
What could be the issue here ?

Comment: can you please check what api versions are installed in the cluster using kubectl api-reosurces and check if that particular version is available

Comment: I tried 
kubectl api-versions | grep autoscaling

autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2
internal.autoscaling.gke.io/v1
internal.autoscaling.gke.io/v1alpha1

Comment: kubectl api-resources | grep autosc  


horizontalpodautoscalers          hpa                      autoscaling/v2                         true         HorizontalPodAutoscaler
capacityrequests                  capreq                   internal.autoscaling.gke.io/v1         true         CapacityRequest

Comment: Have you checked this github [link](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/11287) and this official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-26).

Comment: This was some issue with helm , tried uninstalling and reinstalling the chart and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This was some issue with helm , tried uninstalling and reinstalling the chart and it worked for me.